# why from_utf8 does not exist in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following sql code that uses `from_utf8` function:

```
SELECT FROM_UTF8(name, ’?’) AS name, COUNT(DISTINCT target) AS cnt
FROM directory_entry_file GROUP BY name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

When I execute this query in the postgresql, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function from_utf8(unix_path, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT FROM_UTF8(name, '?') AS name, COUNT(DISTINCT target) ...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Define a function called `from_utf8` may be.

Comment: Could you please explain in details how can I define the function in postgres?

Comment: There is a convert_from and a convert_to function. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-binarystring.html

Comment: So what exactly do you expect `from_utf8` to do?

Comment: I imported software heritage database([https://docs.softwareheritage.org/devel/swh-dataset/index.html]) in postgresql. Then I want to run above sql code to see the most frequent file name across all the revisions (regarding to the relational schema of the database). Note that the type of name is bytea. I want to convert binary to varchar by using the function (see Unicode functions of [https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/71059.htm]) but it doesn't exist in postgresql. I just use the function in postgresql. Is there any way to add or define the function to postgresql?

Comment: "*Note that the type of name is bytea*"  that very important piece of information should have been in your question. - But you should really fix that broken design and change the column's type to `text`. And why are you reading the manual for "alibaba cloud" if you are looking for Postgres functions?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this info in my question. In alibaba cloud, there is a function called from_utf8(binary, replace) → varchar that I think it doesn't exist in Postgres functions. Am I right? if not, what function is similar to from_utf8 in Postgres functions?

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-CONVERSIONS) the function you are looking for is `convert_from()`

> *Converts a binary string representing text in encoding src_encoding to text in the database encoding*

So the query should probably be:

```
SELECT convert_from(name, 'UTF8') AS name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT target) AS cnt
FROM directory_entry_file 
GROUP BY convert_from(name, 'UTF-8')
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think convert_from function that you suggested is not exacly similar to FROM_UTF8(name, ’?’). Regarding to alibaba cloud, convert_from is similar to from_utf8(binary) --> varchar while I'm using from(binary, replace) --> varchar in my code. Is there any function which is similar to from(binary, replace) --> varchar in Postgres functions?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean with `from(binary, replace)`